# Creating an Object - Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, object

**Problem**

I am trying to create an object in Objective-C. I know how to do it but I have a few questions regarding the methods in the implementation file.

**The Object:**

```
@interface Program : NSObject {
    NSString *sid;
    NSString *le;
    NSString *sd;
    NSString *pid;
    NSString *n;
    NSString *d;
    NSString *url;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *sid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *le;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *sd;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *pid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *n;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *d;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *url;

@end
```

**Question**

I should only implement `dealloc` and `init`.. Am I right on this?

Furthermore, I have no special initializations, so should I keep the default `init` method as follows?

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to `retain` the NSStrings?  If a retained object is actually an NSMutableString, it can change from under you.  I find it rare to `retain` NSString properties; I usually `copy` them.

Comment: Agreed. Everything I've read says to use copy for NSStrings.

Comment: That's right.. I always forget about that! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to synthesize the properties and if you don't need any custom initialization then you can keep the `init` method as it is. In fact there is no need to implement `init` here. But in `dealloc` you need to release the strings.

```
@implementation Program

@synthesize sid;
// ... synthesize others

- (void)dealloc {
    [sid release];
    // ... release others

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

I may be wrong, and I'm sure someone will correct me ;), but if you're not doing any special initializations, you don't need the init method.

Answer (score 1):

> I should only implement dealloc and init.. Am I right on this?

You need to also implement all those properties, but you can make the compiler do all the hard work by `@synthesize`ing them.

Each of the properties needs to be released in your `-dealloc`

Answer (score 1):

if you are creating a properties (**you should synthesize** so the compiler will automatically generate getter and setter methods for us), and if you are doing custom initialization then you need to remember self keyword

```
-(id)init{
  self.sid = @"SID" //Without the self object & the dot we are no longer sending 
                     //an object a message but directly accessing ivar named sid
 }

 - (void)dealloc {
     self.sid = nil;
     [super dealloc];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to implement `- dealloc` and `- init` if you have tear-down or setup to do. If you have none, you don't have to implement either because the defaults inherited from `NSObject` do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to implement dealloc, and release all of your ivars. Also, don't forget to @synthesize your properties!